# Bootstrap - responsive image in panel body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have something like this:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="image-overlay">
    <img class="img-responsive"> src="..."/>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if I set manually height of "panel-body" to 400px. Its working as it should.
However once opening on small display height stays 400px but image is resized to smaller and half of panel is empty. How can I have responsive image in panel with also panel responsive?

Comment: Need more details in your question...   What is desired effect at specified resolutions?   Are you trying to maintain some padding or something in the panel around the image?  Even better if you create a quick [plunker](http://plnkr.co) and include the link with details here about the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

can you try not to put any dimension? try to check this one

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you're probably looking for this:

```
<img src="/mysrc.jpg" style="width:100%;max-height:400px;" />
```